# What kind of JavaScript protection is usually applied on fields to prevent value injection?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, security, passwords

There is a certain website with a certain login form which includes two fields; *username* and *password*.

I can successfully inject data with vanilla JavaScript to the first field:

```
document.querySelector("#username").value = "USERNAME";
```

But when I try to inject a password:

```
document.querySelector("#password").value = "PASSWORD";
```

I get an error:

> VM1766:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
>       at :1:45

### My problem

I double checked if the field exists as is and it is indeed existing in DOM;
 I further ran a code like `console.log(document.querySelector("#password"));` and got lots of output which I purposely evade pasting here due to legal reasons.

### My question

What kind of JavaScript protection is usually applied on fields to prevent value injection?

Comment: Based on the error, it seems that there is no element with ID **password** in the DOM when the `document.querySelector("#password").value = "PASSWORD";` statement is executed.

Comment: @Titus I as someone who do only vanilla suspects, from your comment, that this is something to do with React / "pseudo-DOM" or something of that sort, right? I know almost nothing about React...

Comment: No. What I'm trying to say is that even though `console.log(document.querySelector("#password"));` prints something that doesn't mean that when `document.querySelector("#password").value = "PASSWORD";` is executed, `#password` exists, if you add that statement in the same place where the `console.log(..)` statement is, you won't get any errors.

Comment: @Titus I am stuck in explaining why than I can see this element as existing in the DOM and run `console.log()` on it but getting this error. I think I should use some loop on a parent element to add the value to any `valuable` field the loop finds.

Comment: Oh crap --- I had a typo in the copy paste... I am sorry for time loss for you, dear @Titus ; I send you a good blessing.