# Is there a way to observe a DOM mutation of an element by a CSS selector and if so, how to do so?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, mutation-observers

There is a certain website with a certain HTML element which, if I understand correctly, has the same class at `DOMContentLoaded` event and at `load` event, but sometime after the `load` event, this class (and possibly also the ID and also HTML attributes) get changed.

I would like to "observe" this element from the first moment it exists on DOM, so to automatically follow any change its HTML might have.

Is there a way to observe a DOM mutation of an element by a CSS selector and if so, how to do so?

I ask this assuming I understood the "observation" concept in JavaScript correctly.

Comment: maybe you want something like [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: The answer to the question is no, but as Ma'moun has suggested, MutationObserver can detect changes to attributes in elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to observe a DOM mutation of an element by a CSS selector...

Sort of. You can observe **all** modifications in an element and its descendant elements with a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), and you can use the [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) method on the elements you see added or modified to see whether they match a given CSS selector (or use `querySelector` on the container you're watching).

With the combination of a mutation observer and `matches`/`querySelector(All)`, you can see any change you need to see.

```js
// Get the container
let container = document.getElementById("container");

// The selector we're interested in
let selector = "div.foo";

// Set up a mutation observer
let observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
    // A mutation occurred within the container.
    // `records` contains the information about the mutation(s)

    // If you're looking to see if a new element matching the selector
    // was *added*, you can loop through the added nodes (if any)
    for (const record of records) {
        for (const added of record.addedNodes) {
            if (added.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && added.matches(selector)) {
                console.log("Matching element added: " + added.textContent);
            }
        }
    }

    // If you're looking to see if an element *changed* to match the
    // selector, you can look at the target of each record
    for (const {target} of records) {
        if (target.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && target.matches(selector)) {
            console.log("Element changed to match: " + target.textContent);
        }
    }

    // Or alternatively ignore the records and *why* an element now matches,
    // and just see if any does.
    const found = container.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (found.length) {
        console.log("Matching elements found: " + found.length);
        for (const {textContent} of found) {
            console.log("Matching element found: " + textContent);
        }
    }
});
observer.observe(container, {
    // Tweak what you're looking for depending on what change you want to find.
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true
});

// Add five div elements; the fourth will have the
// class we're interested in.
let counter = 0;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    ++counter;
    div.textContent = "Div #" + counter;
    if (counter === 4) {
        div.className = "foo";
    }
    console.log("Adding div: " + div.textContent);
    container.appendChild(div);
    if (counter === 5) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 200);

// After 1200ms, *change* one of the divs to match the selector
setTimeout(() => {
    const div = container.querySelector("div:not(.foo)");
    console.log("Changing element to match: " + div.textContent);
    div.className = "foo";
}, 1200);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    This is the container.
</div>
```

You'll want to tweak the options you pass the observer and the code in the observer callback to match your scenario of course. :-)

Comment: Hello; I am having an hard time synthesizing an answer from the two linked pages because the first doesn't mention `matches` method and the second doesn't mention the mutation observer interface.

Comment: @ShadowyShade - Right, they're distinct things. As I said above, you'd use `matches` on the elements reported to you by the mutation observer to see if they match the CSS selector you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks T.J ; sadly I found the articles not enough didactic for me personally --- it is likely I will take a course about this in the future ; but, as this question was an effort to deal with a broader problem, you are welcome to review my other two recent (and very short) questions:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293387/what-kind-of-javascript-protection-is-usually-applied-on-fields-to-prevent-value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350849/can-an-html-element-appear-as-if-it-is-in-dom-→-but-not-actually-be-in-dom-and-i

Comment: @ShadowyShade - After my comment above, I added an example to the answer. Happy coding!

Comment: What is the impact on performance due to this?

Comment: @rbansal - How long is a piece of string? :-) If there are no modifications to the page, none. If there are a ludicrous number of modifications to the page, X. It depends entirely on the structure of the page, the number and types of modifications to it, and how much work your mutation observer handler does.